# How to center a form horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, forms, location, alignment

I have a **form** within the **body**. And I'm trying to replace the form at the middle/center of the screen. Is there a proper way to do that in CSS?

```
-----------------------
-                     -
-                     -
-                     -
-          M          -
-                     -
-                     -
-                     -
-----------------------
```

Comment: Updated answer, to reflect edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: (snipped previous code, it only horizontally aligned)

Since no one else got back about vertical align... Here's one option. If the form is just sitting in the body, you don't want a wrapper, etc.. Basic solution (requires a fixed height):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Vertical/Horizontal Align</title>
     <style type="text/css">
         form {
             height:400px;
             width:400px;
             position: absolute;
             left: 50%;
             top: 50%;
             background-color:#CCC;
             /* Set margins to offset 50% of the w/h */
             margin: -200px 0 0 -200px;
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="/something">
         <p>
          <label>NAME: </label> <input type="text" name="Name" />
         </p>
         <p>
         <label>PHONE: </label> <input type="text" name="Phone" />
         </p>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Background color is just to illustrate the width/height..

Comment: What exactly does the `div#FormWrapper` do that you couldn't apply directly to the `form` element?

Comment: Honestly, probably nothing in this situation. I've just gotten into the habit of wrapping my forms in divs, as I find it more flexible when applying JS transitions etc than using a form element as it's own wrapper. Just my personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a width property for your form and use auto left margin, say:

```
form{
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```